# Why is this function in an expression not visible?

Tags: javascript

Why does the following result in an error?

Is `bar` not instantiated before the invocation?

```
(function bar(){}, bar())
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: bar is not defined

Comment: From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function: "*name
The function name [...] is only local to the function body.*"

Comment: Ok, I'll accept that as the answer.

Comment: Change it to `(bar = function(){}, bar())` and it will work